# Is there a font named "Flower Power"?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I just wanted to know that is there is any font named "Flower Power" [that looks like this](http://all-free-download.com/free-vector/vector-flower/flower_power_58475.html):

[image]

Are the two files available for download at the above mentioned page (.eps and .ai) fonts? Can I convert them to .ttf format?

This is my very first question at GraphicDesign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to GD.SE!

What you are seeing is actually an illustration. You can tell it's not a font not only because of the formats (.ai and .eps), but because of the colors. Fonts are a just a set of shapes, so they can only have one color.

There is no easy way of converting graphics into a font (you could create a font using those graphics, but it would take a long time, and you only have those 4 characters).

There are, however, some other fonts that use flowers. A couple of examples:

[**Alpha Flowers**](http://www.dafont.com/alpha-flowers.font?fpp=50) (DaFont - Free)

[image]

[**Vtks Flowers**](http://www.dafont.com/vtks-flowers-in-our-soul.font?fpp=50) (DaFont - Free)

[image]